# How to enable gps icon just like official google map application to redirect to current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-location

Is it possible to show location icon just like official android application 
see image for further reference[image].

I'm using below code to show icon but not working

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution

According to google api to enable location button you must enable location layer and

To enable the My Location layer in your application, you must first add the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions to your application as a child of the  element in your Android manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Take a look at here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location

Answer (score 0):

You can enable by following line

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

not forgot to add gps  permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```